# Django get objects of objects

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have 3 models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   ...

class Group(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="groups")

class Word(models.Model):  
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              related_name="words")
```

I want to get all words that are in a project. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lookups that span multiple relationships:

```
project = Project.objects.get(...)

project_words = Word.objects.filter(group__project=project)
```

Django docs reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships